# Adminer autologin

Tags: php, adminer

My code to run Adminer 4.8.1 looks like this:

```
echo '<iframe id="frame_adminer" src="adminer.include.php" style="width:100%;height:100%;" ></iframe>';
```

and adminer.include.php looks like:

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'user');
define('DB_PSWD', 'password');
define('DB_NAME', 'database');

function adminer_object()
{
    include_once __DIR__.'/plugins/plugin.php';
    foreach(glob(__DIR__.'/plugins/*.php') as $filename) {
        include_once $filename;
    }

    $plugins = [
        new AdminerTranslation,
        new AdminerForeignSystem,
        new AdminerEditCalendar,
        new AdminerVersionNoverify,
        new AdminerLinksDirect,
    ];

    class AdminerCustomization extends AdminerPlugin
    {
        public function name()
        {
            return 'SQL panel';
        }

        public function database()
        {
            return DB_NAME;
        }

        public function credentials()
        {
            return [DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PSWD];
        }

        public function login($login, $password)
        {
            // validate user submitted credentials
            return ($login === DB_USERNAME && $password === DB_PSWD);
        }
    }

    return new AdminerCustomization($plugins);
}

include_once __DIR__.'/adminer.php';
```

Problem is that adminer dont want auto login. It always show me login screen?
Somewhere I read that this will help me:

```
$_GET['username'] = ''; // triggers autologin
```

but no work.

How to say to adminer to loggin without login form?

Comment: your writing your defines wrong, it should be `define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost')` etc

Comment: Ohh sorry, I edited. Now its correct example.

Comment: did it fix the issue?

Comment: Are you really supposed to be defining a class from inside a function?

Comment: Its by Adminer documentation.

Comment: What happens when you append `?username=` to the iframe src?

Comment: Nothink happen.

Answer (score 2):

My implementation was like this:

```
function adminer_object() {
    // required to run any plugin
    include_once "./plugins/plugin.php";

    // autoloader
    foreach (glob("plugins/*.php") as $filename) {
        include_once "./$filename";
    }

    $plugins = array(
        // add you plugins here
    );

    // It is possible to combine customization and plugins:
    class AdminerCustomization extends AdminerPlugin
    {
        function permanentLogin()
        {
            // key used for permanent login
            return 'somerandonstring';
        }
    }

    return new AdminerCustomization($plugins);
}

if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] === '' || empty($_COOKIE['adminer_permanent'])) {
    $_POST['auth'] = [
        'driver'    => 'server',
        'server'    => 'localhost',
        'username'  => 'your user',
        'password'  => 'your password',
        'db'        => 'your database',
        'permanent' => 1,
    ];
}

// include original Adminer or Adminer Editor
include "./adminer.php";
```

Replace your connection details in the $_POST['auth'] array and add a permanent login key.